# How to find shortest paths between one destination and multiple origins in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, network-analyst, shortest-path, closest-facility

I am working on landfill site analysis. I have a landfill site (point) in my data. I want to connect the landfill point with different locations(points) in my study area using shortest paths. I have tried new route and closest facility tools with no success. I am getting route between one destination and one origin only. Could somebody please help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Near tools:  http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/coverage-toolbox/near.htm  and   http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/generate-near-table.htm